# Build a JSON template in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I need to create a json data structure dynamically which has the same template of the following example:

```
[   
    {   
        "Inner_CV_Combs":
        [
            {
                "Hyperparameters":
                {
                    "weight_decay": 0.01,
                    "dropout": 0.3,
                    "batch_size": 16,
                    "learning_rate": 2e-5,              
                },
                
                "Folds":
                [
                    {
                         "Val_F1": 0.87,
                         "Val_Acc":0.80
                    },
                    {
                         "Val_F1": 0.87,
                         "Val_Acc":0.80
                    },
                    
                ],
                
                "Average_F1_Val": 0.77,
                "STD_F1_Val": 0.05,
                "Average_Accuracy_Val": 0.87,
                "STD_Accuracy_Val": 0.03
            },
        ],
        
        "Best_Hyperparameters":
        {
            "weight_decay": 0.01,
            "dropout": 0.3,
            "batch_size": 16,
            "learning_rate": 2e-5,              
        },
        
        "F1_Test": 0.85,
        
        "F1_Class_Report_Test": "null",
        
        "Acc_Test" : 0.75
    },

]
```

In particular:

- The "root" is a list of M elements
- "Inner_CV_Combs" is a list of N elements
- "Folds" is a list of K elements

Initially, the data structure created is empty and it is filled after the creation, since the values are not static and I know only the sizes above.

As a starting point, I created an empty list in this way:

```
list = [ [ [ [] for _ in range(K) ] for _ in range(N) ] for _ in range(M)]
```

But I am not really sure this is correct, since I have to add dict too.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Actually, I have only instantiated an empty list in this way:

list = [ [ [ [] for _ in range(K) ] for _ in range(N) ] for _ in range(M)]

But I think this is not the right method since I have to use dict too. I don't know even how to start with.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. Please update your question with this code you have tried and I'll try to put together an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you a starting point. I've used `copy.deepcopy()` just to make sure each element in a separate copy:

```py
import copy

M = 2
N = 3
K = 4

folds = [{}]*K

inner = [copy.deepcopy({"Folds":folds}) for _ in range(N)]

root = [copy.deepcopy({"Inner_CV_Combs":inner}) for _ in range(M)]
print(root)
```

Output:

```py
[{'Inner_CV_Combs': [{'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, {'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, {'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}]}, {'Inner_CV_Combs': [{'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, {'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, {'Folds': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to quamrana I got the solution:

```
n_splits_outer_cv = 1
n_splits_inner_cv = 2
combinations = 1

inner_cv_folds = [{
    "Val_F1": 0.0,
    "Val_Acc":0.0
    }]*n_splits_inner_cv

inner_cv_combs = [{
    "Hyperparameters":
    {
        "weight_decay": 0.0,
        "dropout": 0.0,
        "batch_size": 0,
        "learning_rate": 0.0,   
    },
    "Folds":inner_cv_folds,
    "Average_F1_Val": 0.0,
    "STD_F1_Val": 0.0,
    "Average_Accuracy_Val": 0.0,
    "STD_Accuracy_Val": 0.0
    }]*combinations

outer_cv_folds = [{
    "Inner_CV_Combs":inner_cv_combs,
    "Best_Hyperparameters":
        {
            "weight_decay": 0.0,
            "dropout": 0.0,
            "batch_size": 0,
            "learning_rate": 0.0,               
        },
        "F1_Test": 0.0,
        "F1_Class_Report_Test": "null",
        "Acc_Test" : 0.0
    }]*n_splits_outer_cv
```

The output is the same as the example.